# Inertia.JS Render View To String

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a laravel jetstream application where I would like to render a vue view into a html string which i will then process elsewhere.

I would like to have

```
$htmlStr = Inertia::render('Claims/Show', ['claim' => $claim,  'permissions' => $permissions]);
```

Is there a way to render inertia templates as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible. It renderes a view response that cannot be converted to a html string.

Comment: Do you think if theres any way around that? Like a way to get php/laravel to render the vue templates into a html string?